# Is it safe to put the client web id in Strings.xml from Google authentication?

Tags: java, android, security

I had a problem generating `client_web_id` using the Google Login API and I researched it. What I found was to manually create a tag in `strings.xml` with the name `default_web_client_id` indicating the Web Client ID. Is it safe to put this information exposed be it in an XML or in a class? Is it dangerous someone discovered the web client id?

On the firebase, I noticed that there is two login configuration information: which are Web Client ID and the Password. Only the Web Client ID is in my source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to put the web client ID in your code. You can put it anywhere in your Android source actually. Because, if someone wants to get the web client id from your code, it can be done decompiling your APK file and accessing the class objects or `strings.xml` files.

If you do not have your web client password in your source code, then I think this is fine.